# Android Constructor is not defined

Tags: java, android, sql, constructor

I am trying to execute different SQL statement for each Swipe View in Android. Here is the part of my onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    expensesCat = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_expensescat_frag,
            container, false);

    DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    TransactionRecController trc = new TransactionRecController(
            mDbHelper.open());

    trans_list = trc.getChartExpensesCat();
    openChart();
    mDbHelper.close();
    return expensesCat;
}
```

And in my controller class:

```
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
public TransactionRecController(SQLiteDatabase mDb) {
    this.mDb = mDb;
}

public ArrayList<TransactionRecModel> getChartExpensesCat() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT SUM(tr.amount) AS total, c.categoryName FROM transactionRec tr " +
                "INNER JOIN category c ON tr.categoryID = c.categoryID " +
                "WHERE tr.type = 'W' GROUP BY c.categoryName";
        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Grab Success");
        if (mCur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    TransactionRecModel trm = new TransactionRecModel();

                    trm.setCategory(mCur.getString(mCur
                            .getColumnIndex("categoryName")));
                    trm.setAmount(mCur.getInt(mCur.getColumnIndex("total")));

                    transList.add(trm);
                } while (mCur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return transList;
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to initialize the DatabaseAdapter, I am getting this error message:

```
The constructor DatabaseAdapter(DashboardExpensesCat) is undefined
```

I wonder how to fix this error as I cannot change the constructor in my controller class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is DashboardExpensesCat ?

Comment: That is the class name of my onCreateView()

Comment: @Crazy: my guess is his `Activity`.
As we don't have access to the constructor method itself, it's not very easy. However, I think you should pass some `Context` instead.

Comment: you should try silentkiller answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing Object of your Fragment

```
DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
```

here `this` mean the instance or object of Fragment. while in this you have to pass the `Context` of an Activity and as you are initializing it in Fragment then you need to pass

```
DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
```